# Kubernetes master is OK yet minions not working

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

On an Ubuntu VM in OpenStack, I have followed the steps as per [this link](http://blog.guthnur.net/kubernetes-ubuntu-installation/)
to install Kubernetes.

When running the following command only the master is getting up but not
the minions. Is this related to VT-x in OpenStack?

Please give me some clue on this.

Terminal output:

```
root@stratos:~/kubernetes/cluster# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-down.sh
Bringing down cluster using provider: ubuntu
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
FLANNEL_NET
172.16.0.0/16
Cleaning on node 127.0.0.1
9910
etcd stop/waiting
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
Done
root@stratos:~/kubernetes/cluster# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
... calling kube-up
FLANNEL_NET
172.16.0.0/16
Deploying master and minion on machine 127.0.0.1


etcd start/running, process 23263
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
Validating master
Validating root@127.0.0.1

Kubernetes cluster is running.  The master is running at:

  http://127.0.0.1

FLANNEL_NET
172.16.0.0/16
Using master 127.0.0.1
Wrote config for ubuntu to /root/.kube/config
... calling validate-cluster
Waiting for 2 ready nodes. 1 ready nodes, 1 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 2 ready nodes. 1 ready nodes, 1 registered. Retrying.
Waiting for 2 ready nodes. 1 ready nodes, 1 registered. Retrying.
```

Comment: I came to know that we can not create two minions on the same machine or VM, so I have successfully installed kubernetes master and one minion.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that we can not create two minions on the same machine or VM, so I have successfully installed kubernetes master and one minion.